# query the attached entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am doing several insert commands before doing SaveChanges.

Is there a way to query the attached entities (that I inserted right now before the SaveChanges) in order to check whether a specific record was added or updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. `ObjectContext` instance offers property called `ObjectStateManger`. `ObjectStateManager` manages all attached entities and it knows their state:

```
ObjectStateEntry entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(attachedEntity);
EntityState state = entry.State;
```

If you need to get all modified or added entities you can use:

```
var entities = context.ObjectStateManager
                      .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntitiSate.Modified)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity);
```

You can further use `OfType` to select only entities of some type. You can also use this logic `SaveChanges` as described many times on Stack Overflow - for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087083/autogenerated-timestamp-in-entity-manager/6087105#6087105).

Comment: Do you know a way how can I wrap the ObjectStateManager methods to interface so that I wont be depend on the db tier?

Comment: Simply by checking MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx you can see that `ObjectStateManager` doesn't implement any interface so if you want any wrapper you must define your own interface and create your own wrapping class.